# how to get a Process ID in c, getpid() is not implemented

Tags: c++, c, process, operating-system, pid

How can I get the process ID in C while getpid() method is not implemented ? I ve got an OS without anything, no libraries, nothing, I have to develop all.

Comment: Don't have much idea but you can start by looking at the existing implementation of `getpid()`.

Comment: Do you even *have* processes? What do you need `getpid` for? What syscalls *are* available?

Comment: Why you can't install the libraries ? On what kind of device is your OS running? Is a linux distribution or RTOS?

Comment: Without knowing the implementation of your processes, and how they are created, managed will be a little hard to give an exact solution.

Comment: Well then you should look at the source code of this custom OS's kernel, see if it keeps process IDs, see if it exposes a syscall to get them, and if not, it will be up to you to add these features in.

Comment: You cannot return a process identifier, but you are writing an OS?  What about the address of the process control block - would that not do?

Answer (score 4):

Nobody here will be able to give an exact answer for an OS that isn't generally available (unless they are or have been in the same course as you)

The generic answer is that you need to introduce a new system call (if the OS is really simple, this would be just a function call, like other OS services - without knowing the OS itself, it's a detail that can't be concretely answered), that checks what the current process is, and returns some form of unique number for that process ID. Could be the pointer to the process control block [as in Windows], the stack pointer [if the OS doesn't have virtual memory so stack is at the same place], or the number of the current process's entry in the process list.

Comment: @JackJohns You could upload the code to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) unlisted.

Comment: I'm not your personal support. and the idea with Stackoverflow is that you ask questions there, not that you find people who will help you on a personal level - that's not what I want to do, and I think MOST people here agree.

Comment: Well, on some systems you could do without a syscall, if information is exposed into pseudo-filesystem. For example, on linux you could look at `/proc/self/status`. So simple implementation of getpid() would be `open(/proc/sel/status); read(); parse();`, no need for syscall.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: That assumes a filesystem (and system calls to open files, read files, etc) - these are unlikely to be implemented in a small operating system that doesn't have a system call for get process ID. Note that this is a task for someone learning how OS's work, not about "what is the process ID of a process in my Linux machine".

Comment: @MatsPetersson Well, small systems like Plan9 and Inferno used that approach - provide pseudo-filesystem(s) and replace bunch of syscalls with just one `read()`. Not that I'm against learning or DIY development. Just pointing to possible alternative